# Is it possible to use response_model data in read_hero function before returning it

Tags: fastapi

I am reading hero with it's foreign key data from database and then return it using response_model. On **read_hero** function bellow, in this line `hero = session.get(Hero, hero_id)`  **hero** is different from what this function return when I print it.

hero and team schema:

```
class HeroBase(SQLModel):
    name: str = Field(index=True)
    secret_name: str
    age: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, index=True)
    sponsor: Sponsor = Field(sa_column=Column(JSON(), nullable=False))
    team_id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, foreign_key="team.id")


class Hero(HeroBase, table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    team: "Team" = Relationship(back_populates="heroes")

class TeamBase(SQLModel):
    name: str = Field(index=True)
    headquarters: str


class Team(TeamBase, table=True):
    id: Optional[int] = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    heroes: List["Hero"] = Relationship(back_populates="team")

class HeroReadWithTeam(HeroRead):
    team: "TeamRead" = None


@app.get("/heroes/{hero_id}", response_model=HeroReadWithTeam)
def read_hero(*,hero_id: int, session: Session = Depends(get_session)):
    hero = session.get(Hero, hero_id) 
    print(hero)
    if not hero:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Hero not found")
    return hero
```

Line: `print(hero)` print out `secret_name='clement' name='John' team_id=1 age=14 id=2`

But the function it self return something like this because of response_model:

```
{
  "name": "John",
  "secret_name": "clement",
  "age": 14,
  "team_id": 1,
  "id": 2,,
  "team": {
    "name": "Orlando Pirates",
    "headquarters": "Orlando",
    "id": 1
  }
}
```

Is it possible to have this data inside read_hero function and use it before returning it.

You can refer from this for full code: https://sqlmodel.tiangolo.com/tutorial/fastapi/relationships/

Comment: You already have that structure - that's what your model is structured as before being returned; the `response_model` only defines how the returned data is to be converted to a pydantic model and then serialized before being returned.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like:

```
hero_dict = HeroReadWithTeam.from_orm(hero).dict
print(hero_dict)
```